# How do you define a custom logger without breaking your guard tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, guard

short question above, more details below (mostly unneccessary but figured they could be useful). I'm kind of new to guard and relatively new to rails but I've set up a nicely working rails project with guard running correctly (with rspec). The main thing is that both guard and the custom logger work perfectly and as expected by themselves but the logger will break guard when it is enabled.

details follow: if I define a custom logger like so:

```
logfile = File.open("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log", 'a')
logfile.sync=true
MY_LOGGER = Logger.new(logfile)
```

in a file such as "/lib/assets/my_logger.rb"

if I require this in my config/development.rb file like so:

```
require "assets/my_logger"
```

then I can use this logger within any of my controllers, however as soon as I put it in there, e.g.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
      MY_LOGGER.info "this will break guard tests"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Then my guard tests that depend on this action in the controller will break:

(with MY_LOGGER line commented above):

```
16:56:33 - INFO - Running: spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/Users/crashandburn4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"]...
..................

Finished in 1.61 seconds
18 examples, 0 failures
```

(with line in place)

```
16:56:19 - INFO - Running: spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/Users/crashandburn4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"]...
..FFF.............

Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Sign in') }
       expected #has_title?("Sign in") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
       expected #has_selector?("div.alert.alert-error", {:text=>"Invalid"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication signin with invalid information after visiting another page 
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Home" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "Home"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.62 seconds
18 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:20 # Authentication signin with invalid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:21 # Authentication signin with invalid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:24 # Authentication signin with invalid information after visiting another page
```

(apologies for the unneccessary stacktraces)

now I've been looking around at the guard github page but can't easily find anywhere it says anything about enabling my custom logger so that it is ignored by guard, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requiring the logger in `config/development.rb`, which means that `MY_LOGGER` is undefined in the test environment, breaking your functionality so that the specs are correctly failing. Just move the require to `config/environment.rb` to make it available in all environments.